# How can I get the emoji name from an awaitReactions

Tags: discord.js

So here I'm trying to get a reaction and check what emoji it was reacted with.However, I'm not completely sure how I would do this.

```js
      WarnMsg.react('⬅️')
      .then(() => WarnMsg.react('➡️'))
      .then(() => WarnMsg.react(''))
      const filter = (reaction, user) => user.id === receivedMessage.member.user.id
      WarnMsg.awaitReactions(filter, { time: 30000, max: 1 })
      .then(collected => {
        console.log(collected)
        if(reaction.emoji.name === ''){
          WarnMsg.delete()
          receivedMessage.delete()
        }
        else if(reaction.emoji.name === '⬅️'){
          if(PageNumber == 1)return
          PageNumber = PageNumber - 1
        }
```

That is the current code I have but I'm still confused on how I would go about getting the emoji name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you code, collected return a `collection` of reaction, so you need get first collected element.

```
      WarnMsg.react('⬅️')
      .then(() => WarnMsg.react('➡️'))
      .then(() => WarnMsg.react(''))
      const filter = (reaction, user) => user.id === receivedMessage.member.user.id
      WarnMsg.awaitReactions(filter, { time: 30000, max: 1 })
      .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first()
        if(reaction.emoji.name === ''){
          WarnMsg.delete()
          receivedMessage.delete()
        }
        else if(reaction.emoji.name === '⬅️'){
          if(PageNumber == 1)return
          PageNumber = PageNumber - 1
        }
```

But if you want to handle more then 1 reaction , it`s not right way. Because if you set `max: 1` to `max:40`, event `.then(collected => {` tirgger only when all reaction will be collected or time end. So you need use event `createReactionCollector` , then you can handle every reaction.

**Some example:**

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return ([`◀️`, '▶️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) || [`667456912471883779`, '667456950207905824', '667456934718210059'].includes(reaction.emoji.id)) && user.id === message.author.id;
        };
        const collector = msg.createReactionCollector(filter, {
            max: 50,
            time: 60000,
        });
        collector.on('collect', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
            if (reaction.emoji.name === `◀️`) {
                    // do somethink
            } else if (reaction.emoji.name === `▶️`) {
                            // do somethink
            } else if (reaction.emoji.id === `667456912471883779`) {
                       // do somethink
            } else if (reaction.emoji.id === `667456950207905824`) {
                        // do somethink
            } else if (reaction.emoji.id === `667456934718210059`) {
                    // do somethink
            }
        });
        collector.on('end', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
            msg.clearReactions();
        });
```